# How to stop cURL from writing over downloaded files

Tags: macos, terminal, curl

I'm using

```
$ xargs -n 1 curl -O < gwurls.txt
```

to grab a long list of files. Unfortunately, the site I'm grabbing from relies on the path to provide uniqueness, so `-O` doesn't know the difference between `a/1.pdf` and `b/1.pdf` and clobbers the file.

Is there a simple way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of approaches:

- Do `umask 222` (or `umask 277`, if your umask is currently 77; i.e., add 200 to your umask). 
  This will cause all files that you create to be protected `r--`*(whatever)*
  instead of `rw-`*(whatever)*, so, once you’ve created a file, you shouldn’t be able to overwrite it without `chmod`ing it first (unless you’re running as root).  This answers the question you posed in your title, but it doesn’t really solve your problem; it just means that you’ll successfully download and retain `a/1.pdf` and miss out on `b/1.pdf`, rather than the other way around. 
  (If it’s any consolation, you’ll get error messages alerting you to the collisions.)
- The problem seems to lie in your `gwurls.txt` file, which naïvely lists both `a/1.pdf`
  and `b/1.pdf`, so try to fix it there.  Mangle it with `sed` or something to look like

```
  a/1.pdf    a_1.pdf
  b/1.pdf    b_1.pdf
```

… and then write a script that runs `curl` with a URL of `$1` and an output specification of `$2`, and run

> `xargs -n 2`*your_script*`< modified_gwurls.txt`

so `xargs` will run

> *your_script*  `a/1.pdf  a_1.pdf`
>   *your_script*  `b/1.pdf  b_1.pdf`

This gets messy if any of the filenames have whitespace in them –– but I guess that isn’t possible for URLs, is it?

Comment: I was completely focused on the curl call and avoided the obvious, which was modifying the scrape. Thanks for the perspective.

Answer (score 0):

#### Wget

The by far easiest solution would be [installing Wget](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/22/install-wget-mac-os-x/) and executing the following command:

```
wget --input-file=gwurls.txt
```

Wget automatically renames the output file if a file of the same name already exists.

#### Renaming

If you strip scheme and host (e.g., `http://example.com/`) from the URL, you can replace all slashes with underscores (or any other character) and save the files like that. To be on the safe side, you could replace pre-exisiting underscores with double underscores.

With bash, this should work:

```
while read -r URL; do
    OUTPUT="${URL#http://example.com/}"
    OUTPUT="${OUTPUT//_/__}"
    OUTPUT="${OUTPUT//\//_}"

    curl --output "$OUTPUT" --url "$URL"
done < gwurls.txt
```

How it works:

- `while read -r URL; do ... done < gwurls.txt` reads the contents of *gwurls.txt* line by line and stores the entire line (without leading or trailing spaces) into the variable *URL* and executes `...`.
- The three `OUTPUT=...` commands perform the mentioned replacements using [bash string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).
- `curl --output "$OUTPUT" --url "URL"` downloads the file and stores it with the desired filename.

#### Directory structure

It's also possible to re-create the directory structure of the server using a similar approach.

With bash, this should work:

```
while read -r URL; do
    OUTPUT="${URL#http://example.com/}"

    curl --create-dirs --output "$OUTPUT" --url "$URL"
done < gwurls.txt
```

Here, the `--create-dirs` switch makes cURL create the directory `a` if *OUTPUT* reads `a/1.pdf`.

Comment: Agree, wget would've been the best approach, but needed a curl solution. Why cURL doesn't have auto-renaming built-in is curious.